# Why launching a shell script from Debian service does not behave as command line?

Tags: bash, debian, systemd

I have a python bot that I launch in command line and askes me a login to start working.

To skip this step, I add a pipe to directly insert the login in the command as the following and it works :

```
printf "login" | python_module-py
```

Now, I want to schedule the bot's launch to don't have to launch it by myself and avoid the bot needing my computer always on.

So I bought a Debian VPS and tried to create a systemd service. I put the command in a shell. Here is my service : (assuming my script is in /home/user and I have all the rights rwx)

```
[Unit]
Description=Description
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
Group=group
WorkingDirectory=/home/user
ExecStart=./script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried to start it but it failed because of this error :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I'm almost sure that's because the login is not passed through the pipe and I'm wondering why.

Please, pardon me in advance for my english.

[ALSO TESTED]

Keep the command in the service using `/bin/sh -c` also giving the same error :

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/printf "login" | /usr/bin/python3.7 -m python_module'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

In my case, I had to use the xargs command to ensure that the text pasted in the pipe is really pasted.

```
printf "login" | xargs python_module-py
```

Answer (score 0):

The pipe won't work directly in an e.g. `ExecStart` statement, instead you should use something like `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'printf "login" | python_module-py'` to let `/bin/sh` handle the pipe.

You should also be able to pass a file as standard input to your service, by setting [`StandardInput`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardInput=).

Comment: Hi Sebastien, thank you for your response and your time. I edited my question to give more information. I already saw in a SO post that service is not full shell so we have to use the `/bin/sh/ -c`. So I edited my ExecStart to : `/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/printf "login" | /usr/bin/python3.7 -m python_module`